# Need to change the application download option

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.1-lollipop

I have updated my mobile software from kitkat to lollipop. While updating, I was prompted to download the software over three option. I chose wi-fi. But when the software is updated, I am getting an error in notification area that "**download size requires wi-fi"**. This is happening for all the application that needs update.
I tried to change the option for download in playstore setting to "**Auto update at any time. Data charges may apply**" but no luck. I have Moto E (2nd Gen).

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

--Nitin

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the app manager in the android settings and clearing the cache and data on google play.  If that doesn't work try uninstalling updates. If that doesn't work try to clear the default settings if there are any.

I'm pretty confident that one of those should fix it. If not you might want to look in XDA developers for your phone to see if there are any known bugs.

-Asloss